# I have written a code to calculate the correlation between two Pandas Series. Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def correlation(x, y):
    std_x = (x - x.mean())/x.std(ddof = 0)
    std_y = (y - y.mean())/y.std(ddof = 0)
    return (std_x * std_y).mean

a = pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 7, 9])
b = pd.Series([12, 10, 9, 7, 3])
ca = correlation(a, b)
print(ca)
```

It does not return the value of the correlation, instead it returns a Series with keys as `0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and values as `-1.747504, -0.340844, -0.043282, -0.259691, -2.531987`.

Please help me understand the problem behind this.

Comment: You need to *call* `.mean`, eg: `return (std_x * std_y).mean()`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `mean()` with:

```
return (std_x * std_y).mean()
```

not only :

```
return (std_x * std_y).mean:
```

which returns the method itself. Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def correlation(x, y):
    std_x = (x - x.mean())/x.std(ddof = 0)
    std_y = (y - y.mean())/y.std(ddof = 0)
    return (std_x * std_y).mean()

a = pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 7, 9])
b = pd.Series([12, 10, 9, 7, 3])
ca = correlation(a, b)
print(ca)
```

Output:

```
-0.984661667628
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `scipy.stats.stats` to calculate a [Pearson correlation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html). At a minimum, you can use this as a quick check your algorithm is correct.

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr   
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 7, 9])
b = pd.Series([12, 10, 9, 7, 3])

pearsonr(a, b)[0]  # -0.98466166762781315
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth mentioning that you can also ask pandas directly to calculate the correlation between two series using [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.corr.html) which also allows you to specify the type of correlation:

```
a = pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 7, 9])
b = pd.Series([12, 10, 9, 7, 3])

a.corr(b)
```

will then return

```
-0.98466166762781315
```

You can apply `corr` also on a [`dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) which calculates all pairwise correlations between your columns (as each column is perfectly correlated with itself, you see `1s` on the diagonal):

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 8]}).corr()

          a         b
a  1.000000  0.960769
b  0.960769  1.000000
```